# Calculate K(x), which is a function that is equal to the number of irreducible fractions $a/b$ up to $n$.

Tags: combinatorics

For each $x > 0$, $K(x)$ is equal to the number of irreducible fractions $\frac{a}{b}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers and 
$1$ $\leq$ $a$ $\leq$ $x$ 
$1$ $\leq$ $b$ $\leq$ $x$
For example $K$$($$\frac{5}{2}$$)$ $=$ $3$, because there three are fractions which fulfill the requirement $(\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{1})$ which are from $1$ to $\frac{5}{2} = 2.5$
How can I calculate $K(x)$?. What i thought of is trying to find formula for only the whole numbers first. What I know is that is the total of these types of fractions up to $x$ is $x^2$. Then I remove the ones where $a = 1$ because they are always irreducible so $x^2 - x$. Then I remove all the times where $a$ and $b$ are both even. We also have to remove the cases where $a = b$ but have to use the inclusion-exclusion principle because some of these sets intersect. The problem is I am stuck on how to formulate these things formally.

Comment: This seems very similar to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4422267/prove-that-sum-j-1n-f-fracnj-n2-where-fx-is-the-number-of

Comment: The closed formula is $$K(x)=-1+2\sum_{n\leq x}\phi(n)=-1+\sum_{d\leq x}\mu(d)\lfloor x/d\rfloor(\lfloor x/d\rfloor+1)$$ with the added condition $K(x)=0$ if $x<1.$ (Here, $\phi$ is Euler's function and $\mu$ is the Möbius function.) There isn't a good formula that doesn't essentially require factorization of each $n<x$ into primes. We have a known asymptote, $$K(x)\sim\frac{6x^2}{\pi^2}.$$

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A018805](https://oeis.org/A018805) and references there.